# PyroCMS language support

Tags: codeigniter, localization, internationalization, globalization, pyrocms

Our custom modules in PyroCMS need to support multiple languages. How is this done? Particularly:

1. Where do we put the language folders and files? We assume in `/addons/<module name>/language/`. Is this right?
2. Must we provide a translation of our content (content that is specific to our modules) in ***all*** of the PyroCMS supported languages? For example, we are adding the "Gibberish" language and want to define `"greeting" = "Gibberish Hello"`. Must we also define `"greeting"` in english, etc.?
3. Conversely, must we also translate into "Gibberish" language the terms that PyroCMS supports? For example, the "English" translation `"cp_title" = "Control Panel"` must be translated into `"cp_title" = "Gibberish Control Panel"`, etc.?
4. Setting "?lang=zz" (where "zz" is the language we tried to add) gave us the following error:

   > A PHP Error was encountered
   >
   > Severity: Notice
   >
   > Message: Undefined index: en
   >
   > Filename: core/MY_Controller.php
   >
   > Line Number: 83

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered this on or forums, but once again: here is the documentation:

http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.2/manual/developers/contributing/translating-language-files

Comment: Here's a host that's serving the pyrocms 2.2 docs - http://enlivenapp.com/pyro22docs/developers/contributing/translating-language-files

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this answer after reading the post in pyro's forums. Let me contribute it here too:

I think taking a look at the *Galleries* module -bundled with Pyro, created by the dev team- will give you a clear idea on how to take care of most of this.

In galleries, language files follow this structure: modules/galleries/language/language-name/galleries_lang.php

About 3, I think those should be placed in system/cms/language/lang-name/ (and, if you can, you should contribute "Gibberish" language to the Pyro community :) )

I'm not 100% sure about 4, but I'm sure I saw something in the docs.